# back to first activity from each activity and recreate first activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activity, I want to return to the first activity and Refresh it after clicking on the button at second and Third activity, without using "`new Intent(...)`"!

I use this code:

```
ActivityFirst actFirst = (ActivityFirst) _context;
actFirst.recreate();
```

but it doesn't work! with Error : java.lang.ClassCastException

Is there any way to refresh first activity from second or third activity without use below code?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityFirst.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refresh your first `Activity` because the thread is paused when the `Activity` is not in the foreground. Also the reason you are getting a `ClassCastException` I'm assuming is because your trying to cast your second or third `Activity` into the first `Activity` by passing your current `Context`.

You should just refresh your first `Activity` inside `onResume` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    recreate();
}
```

To start your first `Activity` again you could call this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: onResume() of FirstActivity ?

Comment: What we have to write in button's click of second or third Activity ?

Comment: Do you want to actually go to the first `Activity` again? Or stay on the `Activity` you're currently on until the user goes back? If you want to return to the first `Activity` you'll have to either A) call finish() on your `Activity` until you get back to the one you want to be at or B) Start that `Activitie`'s `Intent` again, you can set flags to make it the top of the stack so it's like it's the first `Activity` again. But you said you didn't want to do B) in your question.

Comment: add this line to your `Intent` when calling the first `Activity` again if you would like to do B).

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: I just realized you're not the person who asked the question. You'll have to give me more information if you want me to help you.

Comment: As mentioned in Question, first activity should be called from the click event of button which is in SecondActivity. But what should be there inside click() method ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Swap out FirstActivity for the name of your first `Activity` and 'this' would become `getActivity()` if you are calling it from a `Fragment`. Setting those flags means the other two `Activities` won't be on the `backstack` anymore.

Comment: Why would you not want to use an `Intent`? It's the correct thing to do. You could just call `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish second or third activity when you click on button on these activity then just use onActivityResult in First Activity and refresh you first activity.
If you only want to refresh without finish second ot third activity then send broadcast message to first activity.

Let me know this is useful for you?

Comment: Actually I have ListView on First Activity and I want Refresh that base on result from second and third activity.

Comment: Then refresh in OnActivityResult method of first Activity. Write setResult(ResultOK) and finish() inside button click of second and third activity. It'll called OnActivityResult of previous Activity.

Comment: What should be written in there of button's click event which in there in second Activity ?

Comment: Read about onActivityResult when we want to update something when there are some changes then we use it. Take example:
A->B->C then when you will click on C activity button then check you want to send updated info if yes then write  setResult(ResultOK) and finish() and OnactivityResult of B will be called. Again call B's onActivityResult  setResult(ResultOK) and finish()  then you will get call in A's onActivityResult and you can refresh inside A.

Answer (score 0):

Go through Activity Life Cycle, When you have opened the 2nd activity the first activity will be in pause state.so while resuming the activity you can refresh the activity.
Try these method to implement it : 
`onResume()`
`onPause()`

Comment: What should be written in there of button's click event which in there in second Activity ?

Answer (score -2):

```
startActivity(new Intent(B.this,A.class)); 
finish();
```

If you pass Intent from second activity(**B.this**) to first activity(**A.class**) ; it will be recreate that first activity. When you press back than not second activity open because of **finish();**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your answer. Thank you.